What's the idiomatic way to instantiate a tuple of evars in Ltac2?
Suppose that I have a local definition of a type ty in the context, and ty can be any nested tuple, e.g.:
ty:= (nat * (bool * nat))%type : Type

I am trying to instantiate some evars that, when composed, have type ty, so eventually I would like the context to become:
ty:= (nat * (bool * nat))%type : Type
ident1:= ?ident1 : nat
ident2:= ?ident2 : bool
ident3:= ?ident3 : nat
tuple:=(ident1, (ident2, ident3))

I am new to Ltac2, and here is my initial attempt:
pose (nat, (bool, nat)) as ty.

From Ltac2 Require Import Ltac2.
Ltac2 rec evar_tuple (arg: constr) : constr :=
  lazy_match! arg with
  | prod ?a ?b =>
    let evar_a :=  (evar_tuple a) in
    let evar_b :=  (evar_tuple b) in 
    constr:(prod $evar_a $evar_b)
  | ?a =>
    let arg_i := Fresh.fresh (Fresh.Free.of_ids []) ident:(arg) in
    (* I don't find an Ltac2 version of evar *)
    (ltac1:(a arg |- evar (arg: a)) (Ltac1.of_constr a) (Ltac1.of_ident arg_i));
    (Control.hyp arg_i)
  end.
(* how do I get the body of ty and feed it to evar_tuple? *)

Is this the right way to do it?

I think you are looking for something like this:
From Ltac2 Require Import Ltac2 Printf.
Ltac2 rec evar_tuple (ty: constr) : constr :=
  let ty := eval hnf in $ty in (* allows you to pass `ty` instead of having to pass `(nat * (bool * nat))%type` *)
  lazy_match! ty with
  | prod ?a ?b =>
      let evar_a := evar_tuple a in
      let evar_b := evar_tuple b in
      constr:(@pair $a $b $evar_a $evar_b) (* typing constraints on the evars are enforced here;
note that this will give you an evar with evar type,
rather than a typed evar, if you pass it a type that is not a prod *)
  | ?a =>
      let arg_i := Fresh.in_goal @h in (* this uses base name "h" *)
      epose _ as $arg_i; (* _ gives a new evar, use '_ or open_constr:(_) in other contexts *)
      Control.hyp arg_i
  end.
Goal True.
  pose (nat * (bool * nat))%type as ty. (* note that you need `nat * stuff`, not `(nat, stuff)` *)
  let ev := evar_tuple &ty in
  printf "%t" ev. (* (h, (h0, h1)) *)
  (* 1 focused goal (shelved: 3) (ID 15)

  ty := (nat * (bool * nat))%type : Set
  h := ?Goal : nat
  h0 := ?Goal0 : bool
  h1 := ?Goal1 : nat
  ============================
  True
*)


Many thanks, this is exactly what I am looking for!
